# Java - add 2 numbers together (as strings, can't use parse.int)

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I need to have 2 command line arguments as 2 numbers that are strings. Then using a loop, add the numbers together. For example,

> > > Java AddStrings 123 456
> > >
> > > The sum is: 579

It's for an assignment in class, having trouble figuring out what the loop would be. I can't just convert the strings to integers using parse.Int either. Any ideas?

Comment: Youve posted too early. Try something first then come back if you get stuck

Comment: Hint: Think about the way you add numbers by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use "+" to add them together. I think that you are overthinking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you find the length of the string. Loop over each individual character (I would start at the end of the string and work backwards). Then for each iteration of the loop you would take the char convert that to an int (through type casting) and add it to your total. Each time you step make sure to multiple your number by a power of ten. take that value then add them and then output your answer. (not gonna give you code cus its a homework assignment ;) )

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
int b = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
```

Very simple. I found a lot just looking at Google. Or:

```
Integer i = new Integer(args[x]);
```

Comment: The assignment clearly requires adding the numbers *as strings* without converting them to integers.

Comment: @DavidConrad I think what OP means was that you cannot parse the entire Sting as integer and add them up. I think converting single char into digits are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

First,you take the input.Let s1 and s2 be the 2 strings.The required loop is like this:-

```
String ar[]={s1,s2};
int n=0;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
n+=Integer.parseInt(ar[i]);
System.out.println("The sum is:-"+n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String addStrings(String num1, String num2) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int carry = 0;
      int i = num1.length() - 1;
      int j = num2.length() - 1;

      while (i > -1 || j > -1) {
          int sum = carry + (i < 0 ? 0 : num1.charAt(i--) - 48);
          sum += j < 0 ? 0 : num2.charAt(j--) - 48;
          sb.append(sum % 10);
          carry = sum / 10;
      }
      return sb.append(carry == 1 ? "1" : "").reverse().toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Need to parse each character of a Strings to calculate the sum as below:**

```
private static String calcSum(String a, String b) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    int carry = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=a.length()-1, j=b.length()-1; i>=0 || j>=0; i--,j--) {
        char charA = (i>=0)? a.charAt(i) : '0';
        char charB = (j>=0)? b.charAt(j) : '0';
        sum = charA-'0' + charB-'0' + carry;
        carry = (sum>=10)? 1 : 0;
        res.append(sum%10);
    }
    if(sum>=10) {
        res.append(1);
    }
    return res.reverse().toString();
}
```